# Maximum number of daily quests a player can get?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Question is straight forward. Say you didn't complete any of the daily quests yet or you don't play HotS much.

How many of them a player can hold?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only have three quests available at any given time.

A few things to note regarding these:

- When "quest 4" would have come around, it does *not* erase an old quest to make room, you continue to have the three prior and none "queue" up.
- Everyone is given a random quest each day, meaning that your friend and you could have got two completely different quests.
- You *cannot* have two completely identical quests at the same time. i.e. You'll never have two "Play Diablo characters" quests, but you could have a "Play StarCraft characters" and a "Play Diablo characters."
- You *can* progress through multiple quests at a time. So if you had a 'Support' and 'Warcraft', you could play Lili and make progress towards both.